# Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

i have bloc that control my page, when the icon pressed i want to set the state to initial state, but i got Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close

this is my bloc code

```
class ForgotPasswordBloc
    extends Bloc<ForgotPasswordEvent, ForgotPasswordState> {
  UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();

  @override
  ForgotPasswordState get initialState => ForgotPasswordInitial();

  @override
  Stream<ForgotPasswordState> mapEventToState(
      ForgotPasswordEvent event) async* {
    if (event is RequestOTP) {
      yield ForgotPasswordInitialLoading();

      try {
        bool result = await _userRepository.requestOtp(
            forgotPasswordCredentials:
                ForgotPasswordCredentials(noHp: event.noHp));

        if (!result)
          yield ForgotPasswordInitialFailure(error: "Phone number is invalid");
        else
          yield ForgotPasswordOTP();
      } catch (e) {
        yield ForgotPasswordInitialFailure(error: e.toString());
      }
    }

    if (event is BackToLoginInitial) {
      print("msk sini");
      yield ForgotPasswordInitialLoading();
    }
  }
}
```

this is my page, and the button back

```
state is ForgotPasswordOTP
                          ? Positioned(
                              top: 66,
                              left: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_back,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    iconSize: 30,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // if (state is ForgotPasswordOTP)
                                      forgotPasswordBloc
                                          .add(BackToLoginInitial());
                                    }),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Please be specific about your problem. There is not enough information for people to help you.

Comment: it depends how you pass bloc. Do you use BlocProvider?

Comment: Did you fix it?